# 200GB Sqlite database file search and retrieve

Tags: python, sql, database, sqlite

I have a 250GB sqlite database file on an SSD drive and need to search through this file and search for a specific value in a table.

I wrote a script to perform the lookup in python and here is a similar sql statement to the one that I wrote:

```
SELECT table FROM database WHERE table like X'003485FAd480'.
```

I am looking to compare between hex values stored in a table to a given hex value.I am using Anaconda command prompt and not sure if this is the best route.

My question is about possible recommendations or tools to help speed up the lookup?

Thanks!

Comment: LIKE runs on strings, not blobs. And "hex" describes a textual representation of a value, not a type. Are the values in the table blobs or strings?

Comment: Yes, they are blobs.

Answer (score 2):

LIKE converts both operands into strings, so it might not work correctly if a value contains zero bytes or bytes that are not valid in the UTF-8 encoding.

To compare for equality, use `=`:

```
SELECT ... FROM MyTable WHERE MyColumn = x'003485FAD480';
```

This search can be sped up with an index on the lookup column; if you do not already have a primary key or unique constraint on this column, you can create an index manually:

```
CREATE INDEX MyLittleIndex ON MyTable(MyColumn);
```

Comment: Yeah, this does not work. I will try something else.

Answer (score -1):

I don't know if this is what your looking for, you mentioned using Python. If you're searching different values that are in Python, have you thought about writing two functions, one to search the database and one to compare those results and do something with them?

```
def queryFuntion():
    cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={SQLite3 ODBC Driver};SERVER=localhost;DATABASE=test.db;Trusted_connection=yes') #for production use only
    cursor = cnxn.cursor()
    query = cursor.execute("SELECT table FROM database")
    for row in cursor.fetchall():
        yield str(row.table)

def compareFunction(row):
    search = '003485FAd480'
    if row == search:
        print('Yes')
    else:
        print('No')
```

Comment: Thanks DanB, this is useful.